# java.net.UnknownHostException when starting Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

After installing spark following this.
https://www.davidadrian.cc/posts/2017/08/how-to-spark-cluster/

I got this message :

```
n@jupyter:~$ spark-shell
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
java.net.UnknownHostException: jupyter: jupyter: Name or service not known
  at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1505)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:891)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.org$apache$spark$util$Utils$$localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:884)
  at e(Utils.scala:941)
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112-release)

scala> 1+1
res0: Int = 2
```

I am not sure why spark is looking for jupyter class, 
since this is only shell launching.

EDIT :
Add bashrc config.

```
export PATH=/home/noel/pycharm/jre/bin:$PATH

export HADOOP_HOME=/home/xxx/hadoop_275
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export SPARK_HOME=/home/xxx/spark/spark22_hadoop27
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

etc/host :

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#127.0.1.1  deep-learning

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: Looks there configuration issue on machine on which you run Spark and hostname `jupyter` cannot be resolved. Why? Impossible to tell for sure without seeing you how you prepared the environment. Start with checking `/etc/hosts`

Comment: updated with current config....

Answer (score 0):

adding jupyter in hosts solve this problem.